# SQL: Removing Duplicates in one column while retaining the row with highest value in another column

Tags: sql, duplicates, teradata

I am using Teradata and am stuck trying to write some code... I would like to remove the rows in which columnB has a duplicate value, based on the values in ColumnA - if anyone can help me that would be great!

I have a sequencial number in columnA and would like to retain the row with the highest value in columnA. 
eg. in the below table I would like to retain rows 9,7,6 & 2, because although they have a duplicate in column 2 they have the highest ColumnA value for that Letter.

Table name: DataTable

```
Column1    Column2     Column3     Column4     Column5

     1           B           X           X           X
     2           A           Y           Y           Y
     3           E           Z           Z           Z
     4           B           X           X           X
     5           C           Y           Y           Y
     6           E           Z           Z           Z
     7           C           X           X           X
     8           B           Y           Y           Y
     9           B           Z           Z           Z
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It'd be even better if you added the expected result in same table format as already used.

Comment: You say `ColumnA`, but the table has `Column1` etc.

Comment: ok thanks, duly noted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to select the rows, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.columnA = (select max(t2.columnA) from t t2 where t2.columnB = t.columnB);
```

If you actually want to remove them, then one method is:

```
delete from t
where t.columnA < (select max(t2.columnA) from t t2 where t2.columnB = t.columnB);
```

Comment: Thanks very much that's great :o)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return those rows using a `SELECT` there's no need for a Correlated Subquery, OLAP-functions usually perform better:

```
select *
from tab
qualify
  row_number() over (partition by ColumnB order by columnA DESC) = 1
```

If you actually want to `DELETE` the other rows go for Gordon's query.

Comment: Thanks, thats just what I wanted, it returns rows 2,9,7,6.

Comment: The next step is to delete the other rows so I may need to use Gordon's query

Comment: @Surfing: If there's a large number of rows to delete it might be more efficient to create an empty copy of the table, Insert/Select the rows you want to keep and then Drop/Rename. Or maybe keep the old table until you 100% sure you deleted the right rows :-)

Comment: I deleted 1600 rows, but still have the source data upload file - nothing else has changed since the upload was done so I have a backup. Thanks again :)